# Flutter. SingleChildScrollView doesn't scroll into Positioned widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm using flutter to create an app.
I'm trying to create a sort of box(using Positioned widget) where inside there will be a a scrollable list of widget.
I need a Positioned widget to put in the right postion of stack my "box" widget.
My problem is the list of object doesn't scroll. Any suggestion?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<SoccerMatch>>(
      future: SoccerApi().getAllMatches(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Positioned(
            top: _queryData.size.height * 0.50,
            bottom: -_queryData.size.height * 0.6,
            right: _queryData.size.width * 0.1,
            left: _queryData.size.width * 0.1,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              child:
              Column(
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index)
                    {
                      return matchTile(snapshot.data![index]);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            ),


          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: You will get an Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. error when using Positioned Widget without Stack widget also describe what actullay you are looking for.

Comment: have you tried without the `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` property?

Comment: @Diwyansh I put this widget into a stack in another class, but I have the same issue

Comment: @YounssAITMOU I tried but nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to update your  FutureBuilder with the following

```
          FutureBuilder<List<SoccerMatch>>(
        future: SoccerApi().getAllMatches(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot);
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  top: _queryData.size.height * 0.50,
                  bottom: -_queryData.size.height * 0.6,
                  right: _queryData.size.width * 0.1,
                  left: _queryData.size.width * 0.1,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      child:
                      Column(
                        children: (snapshot.data as List<SoccerMatch>).map((item) => matchTile(item)),
                      ).toList()),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }

          return SizedBox();
        }
      )
```

Comment: I tried but there is a problem on children of coulmn: "The argument type 'Iterable<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>"

Comment: did you add '.toList()' to the children?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to replace your bottom with

```
height: _queryData.size.height * 0.5,
```

Comment: the person who voted down this can tell me the reason?